# "not stripped" but "no debug symbols"

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

Can you explain the different results:

```
$ file libc-2.8.so
libc-2.8.so: ELF 32-bit MSB shared object, PowerPC or cisco 4500, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.10, with unknown capability 0x41000000 = 0x13676e75, with unknown capability 0x10000 = 0xb0401, not stripped
```

Notice the "not stripped" at the end.

and

```
(gdb) file libc-2.8.so
Reading symbols from /opt/Cross_Tools/powerpc-linux-gnu/powerpc-linux-gnu/libc/lib/libc-2.8.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

Notice the "(no debugging symbols found)"

Comment: Because the library was built *without* debugging symbols (the default for e.g. gcc)?

Comment: Absence of debug symbols doesn't imply that the executable is stripped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You typically have to compile in debug mode ([`-g` is the GCC command-line option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options)) to *include* the debug symbols, it's not as if they're always there until stripped out. The default is to build in non-debug mode, without the symbols.