# Print arguments of function without symbols table

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I want to dump with gdb prams of function `foo(struct a*, struct b*)`.

The issue is that in the debugged file only `foo` symbol is available, but not the params:

```
(gdb) info args
No symbol table info available.
```

Is there some way to let gdb know what the signature of the function is?

Comment: Compile with `-g`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["not stripped" but "no debug symbols"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379424/not-stripped-but-no-debug-symbols)

Comment: Related: [Can we define a new data type in a GDB session](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7272558/2554472). You can tell gdb what `struct a` and `struct b` look like, then do `print *(struct a*)$rdi` (or whatever convention your architecture uses for the first parameter to a function).